# How should the title of a chapter or section be formatted when mentioned in the text?

Tags: research-process, thesis, writing

How should the title of the chapter or section be formatted when mentioned in the text?
I mean the titles of chapters of the same work.

For example:

If the chapter is entitled "Chapter Four: Review of the Literature," is the following correct?

> All the studies discussed in the "Review of the Literature" chapter
>   are Western-oriented.

Comment: If you are writing a thesis, questions of this nature are probably best answered by looking at sample theses from your own institution. Your supervisor should be able to provide some sample theses to use as a guide.

Comment: @mhwombat I agree completely. In many schools they will also give you a formal document which explains all of these formatting rules (including font, page numbers, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure this question is on-topic here; this is a general question about writing style, and not specific to academia.

However, it is usually best to refer to chapters by number.

> All the studies discussed in Chapter 4 are Western-oriented.

This makes it easier for the reader to find the relevant chapter without needing to flip back to the table of contents.  It also avoids confusion in case there are several chapters with similar titles.

Your word/text processor software should have a way to automatically maintain the cross reference, in case you rearrange chapters and the numbers change.

Comment: "this is a general question about writing style, and not specific to academia." Except that academia has a very specific and different writing style to... pretty much anything else. That puts it firmly on-topic here, IMHO.